# import specific rows from "txt" into R

Tags: r, import

I have a "example.txt" document just as follows:

```
SIGNAL: 40 41 42                                            
0.406   0.043   0.051   0.021   0.013                   
0.056   0.201   0.026   0.009   0.000                   
0.000   0.128   0       0.009   0.000                               
TOTAL: 0.657                                            
SIGNAL: 44 45 46 48                                         
0.128   0.338   0.026                       
0.333   0.03    0.000                           
0.060   0.013   0.004                           
0.009   0.017   0.009                           
0.013   0       0.000                           
TOTAL: 0.704                                            
SIGNAL: 51 52 54                                            
0.368   0.081   0.085   0.004                       
0.162   0.09    0.064   0.073                       
0.013   0.017   0.009   0.000                       
TOTAL: 0.266                                            
SIGNAL: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67                                         
0.530   0.030                                   
0.009   0.179                                   
0.154   0.004                                   
0.068   0.009                                   
TOTAL: 0.796
```

I want to import the rows between "SIGNAL: 44 45 46 48" and "TOTAL: 0.704" into R, I use `read.table("example.txt",skip=6 ,nrow=5)` to extract these specific rows, it works.

```
     V1    V2    V3
1 0.128 0.338 0.026
2 0.333 0.030 0.000
3 0.060 0.013 0.004
4 0.009 0.017 0.009
5 0.013 0.000 0.000
```

However, my real data (has 450,000 rows) is very big, if I want to extract the rows between "SIGNAL: 3000 3001 3002 3003" and the next"TOTAL", how can I do with it? Thank you so much!

Comment: In the example showed, the number of columns are different in some cases.  Do you want as a single dataset or different datasets for each set of SIGNAL/TOTAL between rows?

Comment: Is `read.table(text = grep("^(SIGNAL|TOTAL)", readLines(file), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE), fill = TRUE)` what you want?

Comment: If we need separate datasets, we read the .txt file with `readLines` .i.e. `lines <- readLines('yourfile.txt'); Map(function(i,j) read.table(text=lines[(i+1):(j-1)], sep='', header=FALSE), grep('SIGNAL', lines), grep('TOTAL', lines))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you! "readline" is amazing, you helped me output all sets, but how can I get only two sets from my big data. For example, I only want  to extract the rows between "SIGNAL: 3000 3001 3002 3003" and the next"TOTAL" and rows between "SIGNAL: 154 155 157" and the next"TOTAL", how can I output these two results in a list form?

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank you! you have helped me output all the data in a uniform, but actually I only want to extract the rows between "SIGNAL: 3000 3001 3002 3003" and the next"TOTAL" and rows between "SIGNAL: 154 155 157" and the next"TOTAL". How can I do with it, thanks!

Comment: Those aren't even present in your example data.

Comment: I have worked it out based on akrun's code. For example, I want to extract the first two sets. I can just use:  `lines <- readLines('example.txt'); g<-c(40,44);  sapply(1:length(g), function(x){Map(function(i,j) read.table(text=lines[(i+1):(j-1)], sep='', header=FALSE), grep(paste('SIGNAL:',g[x]), lines), grep('TOTAL', lines)[which(grep(paste('SIGNAL:',g[x]), lines)==grep('SIGNAL', lines))])})` Thank both of you! @akrun @Richard Scriven

Comment: @lightsnail if you have created your own solution, please post it as an answer to close out the question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out based on akrun's code. For example, I want to extract the first two sets. I can just use:

```
lines <- readLines('example.txt')
g<-c(40,44)
sapply(1:length(g), function(x){Map(function(i,j) read.table(text=lines[(i+1):(j-1)], sep='', header=FALSE), grep(paste('SIGNAL:',g[x]), lines), grep('TOTAL', lines)[which(grep(paste('SIGNAL:',g[x]), lines)==grep('SIGNAL', lines))])})
```